# React Native giving error that variable is not defined when it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have linked an external JS File using require(), it has even recognized it. When i will call a function from that external file it will indicate that the function been recognized but it will still give error that it Can't find the variable (in my case is a function named text()).
**My App.js:**

```
require('./comp/functions.js')
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native'


export default function App() {
      return(<>
      <View style={styles.loginbox}>
        <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 30}}>LOGIN</Text>
        <Button title="Login Now!" onPress={test}/>

      </View>
      </>)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   loginbox: {
     position: "relative",
     top: 100
   }
})
```

**functions.js:**

```
function test() {
    alert(123)
  }
```

I want it to run the test() function when the Login Now! button has been pressed

Comment: You need to export default test function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your functions from your `functions.js` first. And then, you can `import` it into your app. The following should work.

functions.js

```
export default function test() {
  alert(123);
}
```

app.js

```
import test from "./functions";
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.loginbox}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 30 }}>
          LOGIN
        </Text>
        <Button title="Login Now!" onPress={test} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginbox: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 100
  }
});
```